# Get all Airflow Leaf Nodes/Tasks

Tags: airflow

I want to build something where I need to capture all of the leaf tasks and add a downstream dependency to them to make a job complete in our database. Is there an easy way to find all the leaf nodes of a DAG in Airflow?

Comment: The only way I know of right now is by checking the downstream_list and making sure it's empty. Is there a better way

Answer (score 4):

Use `upstream_task_ids` and `downstream_task_ids` [`@property` from `BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2950)

```
def get_start_tasks(dag: DAG) -> List[BaseOperator]:
    # returns list of "head" / "root" tasks of DAG
    return [task for task in dag.tasks if not task.upstream_task_ids]


def get_end_tasks(dag: DAG) -> List[BaseOperator]:
    # returns list of "leaf" tasks of DAG
    return [task for task in dag.tasks if not task.downstream_task_ids]
```

[`Type-Annotations`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html) from `Python 3.6+`

---

**UPDATE-1**

Now Airflow [`DAG` model](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG) has powerful [`@property` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45883083/3679900) like

- [`leaves`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG.leaves)
- [`roots`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG.roots)
- [`topological_sort`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG.topological_sort)

Comment: Also see: [get all parent task_ids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728871/3679900)