# Apache Airflow - get all parent task_ids

Tags: airflow

Suppose a following situation:

```
[c1, c2, c3] >> child_task
```

where all `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and `child_task` are operators and have `task_id` equal to `id1`, `id2`, `id3` and `child_id` respectively.

Task `child_task` is also a `PythonOperator` with `provide_context=True` and `python_callable=dummy_func`

```
def dummy_func(**context):
    #...
```

Is it possible to retrieve all parents' ids inside the `dummy_func`(perhaps by browsing the dag somehow using the context)?

Expected result in this case would be a list `['id1', 'id2', 'id3']`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `upstream_task_ids` and `downstream_task_ids` [*properties* of `BaseOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator.upstream_list) are meant just for this purpose.

```
from typing import List
..
parent_task_ids: List[str] = my_task.upstream_task_ids
child_task_ids: List[str] = my_task_downstream_task_ids
```

---

Do note however that with this `property`, you only get immediate (*upstream / downstream*) neighbour(s) of a task. In order to get all **ancestor or descendent** `task`s, you can quickly cook-up the good old *graph theory* approach such as this `BFS`-*like* implementation

```
from typing import List, Set
from queue import Queue
from airflow.models import BaseOperator

def get_ancestor_tasks(my_task: BaseOperator) -> List[BaseOperator]:
    ancestor_task_ids: Set[str] = set()
    tasks_queue: Queue = Queue()
    # determine parent tasks to begin BFS
    for task in my_task.upstream_list:
        tasks_queue.put(item=task)
    # perform BFS
    while not tasks_queue.empty():
        task: BaseOperator = tasks_queue.get()
        ancestor_task_ids.add(element=task.task_id)
        for _task in task.upstream_list:
            tasks_queue.put(item=_task)
    # Convert task_ids to actual tasks
    ancestor_tasks: List[BaseOperator] = [task for task in my_task.dag.tasks if task.task_id in ancestor_task_ids]
    return ancestor_tasks
```

*Above snippet is NOT tested, but I'm sure you can take inspiration from it*

---

References

- [Get all Airflow Leaf Nodes/Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54455294/3679900)
- [Python Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)
- [Python 3 type-annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: Immediate neighbours are sufficient in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like the below to get all the task ids from within the dag, this should be helpful for anyone looking for a working answer

```
def get_all_upstream_task_ids(task):
   upstream_task_ids = set()
   for upstream_task in task.get_direct_relatives(upstream=True):
       upstream_task_ids.add(upstream_task.task_id)
       upstream_task_ids.update(get_all_upstream_task_ids(upstream_task))
   return list(upstream_task_ids)

get_all_upstream_task_ids(context['task'])
```

Answer (score -1):

A modern approach with Airflow 2

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

...

@task
def task1():
    return "x" 

@task
def task2():
    return "y"

@task
def print_task_ids(x, y, **context):
    dag_run = context["dag_run"]
    tis = dag_run.get_task_instances()

    for ti in tis:
        print(ti.task_id)


@dag(**dag_args)
def show_task_ids():
    print_task_ids(task1(), task2())
    

dag = show_task_ids()
```

Comment: your answer does not event use `x`, `y` parameters that are crucial for getting correct answer.