# How to access xcom_pull outside of task function in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

Code:

```
import datetime
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def hello_world(ti, execution_date, **context):
    logging.info("Hello World")
    return "Gorgeous"


def addition(ti, **context):
    # Want belows are same each other
    logging.info(context['params']["please1"])
    logging.info(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="hello_world"))


dag = DAG(
    "test",
    schedule_interval="@hourly",
    start_date=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1),
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="hello_world", python_callable=hello_world, dag=dag, provide_context=True
)
t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id="abc",
    python_callable=addition,
    dag=dag,
    params={"please1": "{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='{}') }}}}".format(t1.task_id)},
    provide_context=True,
)

t1 >> t2
```

I want `addition()` shows the same result:

```
    # Want belows are same each other
    logging.info(context['params']["please1"])
    logging.info(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="hello_world"))
```

But the result is:

```
[2021-05-17 23:47:15,286] {test_dag.py:14} INFO - {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='hello_world') }}
[2021-05-17 23:47:15,291] {test_dag.py:15} INFO - Gorgeous
```

What I want to know: Is it possible to access `xcom_pull` outside of the task function? e.g. When passing the value from the `xcom` to `PythonOperator`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jinja-templated args for an operator can only be used for those fields that are listed as `template_fields` in the operator class.  For the `PythonOperator` that is `op_args`, `op_kwargs`, and `templates_dict`.  First, replace your `params` parameter to `op_kwargs` and remove the extra curly brackets for Jinja -- only 2 on either side of the expression.  Second, and unfortunately, you need to explicitly list the `task_id` in the `ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='<task_id>')` call.

Revised code:

```py
import datetime
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def hello_world(ti, execution_date, **context):
    logging.info("Hello World")
    return "Gorgeous"


def addition(ti, **context):
    logging.info(context["please1"])
    logging.info(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="hello_world"))


dag = DAG(
    "test",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 17),
    catchup=False,
)

with dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="hello_world",
        python_callable=hello_world,
        provide_context=True,
    )

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="abc",
        python_callable=addition,
        op_kwargs={
            "please1": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='hello_world') }}",
        },
        provide_context=True,
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

Logging from "t2":
[image]

If you are using Airflow 2.0, the code can actually be simplified to use the new `XComArg` feaure.  This feature allows you to access the output of tasks using a simple `task.output` expression.

Revised code with 2.0 and `XComArg` use to access the output of "t1" as the "please1" arg:

```py
import datetime
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


def hello_world(ti, execution_date, **context):
    logging.info("Hello World")
    return "Gorgeous"


def addition(ti, **context):
    logging.info(context["please1"])
    logging.info(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="hello_world"))


dag = DAG(
    "test",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 17),
    catchup=False,
)

with dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="hello_world",
        python_callable=hello_world,
    )

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="abc",
        python_callable=addition,
        op_kwargs={"please1": t1.output},
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

More about DAG authoring with 2.0 [here](https://medium.com/apache-airflow/airflow-2-0-dag-authoring-redesigned-651edc397178).

Comment: Just adding that since version 2.0.0 `provide_context` is deprecated, so there is no need to use it. There is a warning inside the `PythonOperator` code.

Comment: @NicoE Nice catch.  Edited the code sample accordingly.

Comment: @JoshFell One more question: it looks like someone use Jinja in other params except the `template_fields` you mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335683/3595632 . In this case, how can it possible to use Jinja in `data` params?

Comment: @user3595632 For the `SimpleHttpOperator` in that example, the `data` parameter is a template field so Jinja templating is completely fine to use.  I suspect you might be wondering how it's used for the `start` key in the `data` dict.  It's because the entire `data` argument can be templated. Even though the entire `data` argument is not wholly within a Jinja expression, any part of that argument can be. Is this what you are asking?