# Airflow - Specify time of the day for execution timeout parameter

Tags: airflow

My DAG is scheduled to run daily at 7 AM. Can I specify time of the day to execution timeout parameter instead of duration.

For example, I want to add specific time 12 PM so that job will fail if it is still running at 12 PM.

Answer (score 0):

Such a param is not present in [`BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py) or [`DAG`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/dag.py)

---

You'll have a build it. Here's some hint how you can go about it (not certain if this would work)

- Write a custom [`TimeSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L1204) (not to be confused with [`TimeDeltaSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/sensors/time_delta_sensor.py)) by subclassing it, that kills the DAG upon failure.

  - You'll have to override the [`execute()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator.py#L106)
  - For killing you can look into [`_mark_dagrun_state_as_failed()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L1204)
- With the specified `datetime` timeout, add that custom sensor task as one of the [starting tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43529948/3679900) (tasks that don't have an upstream task) of you `DAG`

---

In case you have to timeout some specific task(s) instead of entire DAG

- you can change write another custom timesensor that marks a specific task as failed upon timing out.

  - You can use [`_mark_task_instance_state()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/caa60b1141ac02cdde1c33464be9adca114c2ed5/airflow/www/views.py#L1285) for it
- you can wire up this custom timesensor with that task in *parallel* (so that both the task and it's sensor launch together)